# WebSphere External Jar JNDI bindings

Tags: binding, websphere, jndi, websphere-8

I have a Java EE application which uses an external jar (for logging purpose), but it needs an URL for configuration which is resolved in the jar itself with JNDI lookup.

Some clarification examples:

LoggingLib.jar:
    -> LoggingFactory.java

```
public void resolveJndi(){
     Context ctx = new InitialContext();
     URL myConf = ctx.lookup('url/myConf');
}
```

This lib is included in the real app EAR file and recalled in various class of the application (in web module, ejb module and even in another jar with JPA classes).

Everything works if jndi name 'url/myConf' exists: but I need to map it to a personalized name specified at deploy time. 
For other resources I've resolved this issue using ibm bindings: at deploy time it's asked which is the real jndi name of these resources. this way there's decoupling between software and configuration: the application will look for java:comp/env/url/myConf but the server will resolve it with it's real name.
I've tried doing the same thing with application.xml and ibm-application-bnd.xml but with no success.

What's the right way to do this kind of reference?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done using [URL providers](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/info/iseriesnd/ae/ujtc_ruurl.html). You need to define reference to resource environment in the component where lookup is made from:

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>local_url_reference</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>java.net.URL</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

Then after having URL resource defined, you will be able to bind it into local component's namespace. `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` will look like this (for EJB):

```
  <session name="YourBean">
    <resource-env-ref name="local_url_reference" binding-name="global_url_reference"/>
  </session>
```

Comment: You haven't read all the question: I'm fully aware of how to specify resources on web module and ejbs, my problem is about how to specify resource for an external jar which is included in all projects. At the moment I'm specifying the same resource on all ejbs and in the web.xml but that's a dirty way, I was asking if it was possibile to specify it on application.xml or something like that

Comment: I thought it is clear that binding are specified for Java EE components, which arbitrary JAR is not.